# How can I render a astro component to a HTML string?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I'd like to be able to have a dynamic page in Astro that renders out an Astro component. I've dug into the docs and code, and couldn't find a function like the one below (`Astro.render`). Ideally, I can pass properties into it. I'm looking for something similar to `react.renderToString`.

```js
import Example from './components/Example.astro'

export async function get() {
  return {
    body: Astro.render(Example)
  };
}
```

Update: I think every answer here is getting this wrong. Given an astro file, I want a function within the `node` runtime astro framework independent that can take an astro file and simply return a `Response` (because I know astro files can return a response from front-matter) and or `HTML` string? I'd think it can be a tuple like `[res, htmlString]`. Just like a markdown file can be converted, an astro file as well should be able to be processed.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically render a component in production, or are you just trying to automate something in development?

Comment: FYI: Look at the RSS example https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/rss/#including-full-post-content. CollectionEntry<T> has a `render()` method that will produce a `Content` component. Yet `markdown-it` and `sanitize-html` are used as external dependencies to transform the entry's markdown `body` to HTML. So it seems there is no "blessed" Astro mechanism to transform a component to HTML.

Comment: It's on the roadmap: https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/discussions/409

Comment: Currently proposed in https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/issues/533

Answer (score 10):

### Render Astro Component to html string using Slots

rendering to a html string do exist in Astro, but for slots, if you pass your component in another Wrapper/Serialiser, you can get its html string easily

### Working example

- github repo https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples#16_html-string
- CodeSandbox https://stackblitz.com/github/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples/tree/main/16_html-string

### Usage

This is the body of the Wrapper component, it is being used such as for highlighting but also rendered with the Fragment component

```html
---
const html = await Astro.slots.render('default');
import { Code } from 'astro/components';
---
<Fragment set:html={html} />

<Code code={html} lang="html" />
```

The usage is as follows

in e.g. `index.astro`

```html
---
import Card from '../components/Card.astro';
import StringWrapper from '../components/StringWrapper.astro';
...
---
    <StringWrapper>
        <Card title="Test" />
    </StringWrapper>
```

Comment: This is exacly what you need if you want to transform a string variable to HTML.
In my case, I receive the html as string through an API so ``<Fragment set:html={variable} />`` was the solution.

Answer (score 4):

@HappyDev's suggestion inspired this – while not particularly abstracted and could need some refactoring it does work and allows you to build Astro pages in Strapi using its dynamic zones and components by building corresponding Astro components:

**/pages/index.astro**

```
import SectionType1 from '../components/sections/SectionType1.astro'
// Import all the components you use to ensure styles and scripts are injected`
import renderPageContent from '../helpers/renderPageContent'
const page = await fetch(STRAPIENDPOINT) // <-- Strapi JSON
const contentParts = page.data.attributes.Sections 
const pageContentString = await renderPageContent(contentParts)
---
<Layout>
    <div set:html={pageContentString}></div>
</Layout>
```

**/helpers/renderPageContent.js**

```
export default async function (parts) {

  const pagePartsContent = [];
  parts.forEach(function (part) {
    let componentRequest = {};

    switch (part.__component) {

      case "sections.SectionType1":
        componentRequest.path = "SectionType1";
        componentRequest.params = {
          title: part.Title, // Your Strapi fields for this component
          text: part.Text    // watch out for capitalization
        };
        break;

// Add more cases for each component type and its fields

    }
    if (Object.keys(componentRequest).length) {
      pagePartsContent.push(componentRequest);
    }
  });

  let pagePartsContentString = "";
  
  for (const componentRequest of pagePartsContent) {
    let response = await fetch(
      `${import.meta.env.SITE_URL}/components/${
        componentRequest.path
      }?data=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(componentRequest.params))}`
    );

    let contentString = await response.text();
    // Strip out everything but the component markup so we avoid getting style and script tags in the body
    contentString = contentString.match(/(<section.*?>.*<\/section>)/gims)[0];
    pagePartsContentString += contentString;
  }

  return pagePartsContentString;
}
```

**/components/sections/SectionType1.astro**

```
---
export interface Props {
  title: string;
  text?: string;
}

const { title, text } = Astro.props as Props;
---
<section>
  <h1>{ title }</h1>
  <p>{ text }</p>
</section>
```

**/pages/components/SectionType1.astro**

```
---
import SectionType1 from '../../components/sections/SectionType1.astro';
import urlParser from '../../helpers/urlparser'
const { title, text } = urlParser(Astro.url);
---
<SectionType1
  title={title}
  text={text}
  />
```

**/helpers/urlParser.js**

```
export default function(url) {
  return JSON.parse(Object.fromEntries(new URL(url).searchParams).data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Astro components are rendered on the server, so you can directly reference the included component and pass down props as you want.

```
// [title].astro

---
import Example from './components/Example.asto'
---

<Example message="Hey" />
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a function that converts this file into HTML.

Comment: If using `fetch` is an option to you, I could come up with something

Comment: Yeah I thought about this as well , I might go down that road, it's not exactly what I want though.

Comment: @HappyDev what is the solution using `fetch`?

Comment: @the_brianb using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make an HTTP request to your own server... it's quite a hacky approach though...

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround. But if you're using a [framework integration](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/) like React or Solid, then you can use that framework's `renderToString` method to at least render a framework component.

Example assuming an `Article.tsx` Solid component:

```
import { renderToString } from 'solid-js/web'
import { Article } from '../../components/Article'

const props = { title: 'test', text: 'testtext' }
const htmlString = renderToString(() => Article(props as any))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using vue.js components, leveraging the `h` method from vue.  Of course this means installing vue.js in your project, and a slightly different component structure.

```
<script setup>

import { h } from "vue";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

function renderComponent(data) {
  return h(MyComponent, {data: data});  
}

const externalData = {"my": "data"};

</script>

<template>
  <div v-html="renderComponent(externalData)" />
</template>
```