# Astrojs build custom 500 error page that dynamically shows error message

Tags: typescript, http-status-code-500, astrojs

I have an Astro middleware that intercept the response

```
export const onResponseInterceptor = defineMiddleware(
  async ({ locals, request }, next) => {

    // intercept response
    const response = await next();

  
    // intercept error responses
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      // logging the error to logging service
    }

    if (pathname.startsWith('/api')) {
      // json responses
      return response;
    } else {
      // html responses
      return response;
    }
  }
);
```

And a `500.astro` page

```
---
import BasePublic from './layouts/BasePublic.astro';
---

<BasePublic title='500'>
  <h1>500</h1>
  <p>Internal Server Error</p>
  <p>{message}</p>
</BasePublic>
```

I want to pass dynamic message to the 500 (or the 400) without the need of redirection. It is okay if I can set some param in the url like `?error={dynamicMessag}` but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I had the same problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77300916/214446